# Initialize a collection with a type from another collection

Tags: c#, wpf

This might and impossible scenario and I may be trying to do something that I should not be doing in the first place but here it is.

- I have a custom WPF Control which has two IEnumerable collections
- The first collection (ItemsSource) is declared via the XAML and might be of any type of objects.
- The second collection the one that I am implementing is again an IEnumerable which I want to initialize as ObservableCollection.
- Here is my issue as I am restricted that both the collections are of the same type of objects (no I cannot use object as a type). For example the ItemsSource is of "MyItem" type objects and I want to initialize the second collection to be ObservableCollection().

Is this possible? Am i doing something that I should not be doing? Any hints will appreciated. On a side note if I pass the second collection via the XAML all is well, but I do not want to add such restriction to the feature I am implementing.

Edit:

Here are some code snippets to showcase the scenario:
The first collection, note that this collection is inherited from the `System.Windows.Controls.ItemsControl` class:

```
public IEnumerable ItemsSource { get; set; }
```

The second collection:

```
public IEnumerable SelectedItems
{
    get
    {
        this.InitializeSelectedItemsCollectionIfRequired();
        return (IEnumerable)GetValue(SelectedItemsProperty);
    }
    set
    {
        SetValue(SelectedItemsProperty, value);
    }
}

private void InitializeSelectedItemsCollectionIfRequired()
{
    if (this.GetValue(SelectedItemsProperty) == null)
    {
        // Here is where I want to initialize the second collection if it was not already set in via a Binding in the XAML
        this.SelectedItems = new System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection<"dont know how to pass correct type here">();
    }
}
```

Comment: perhaps some small snippets of code regarding the two collections could be helpful?

Comment: Sorry about that, added a few lines of what I am currently debugging in my post,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you don't know the exact type you could simply revert to the most basic type `object`

```
this.SelectedItems = new System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection<object>();
```

Comment: Yeah I figured that out and it is 100% correct, but I have an restriction that object is not enough and I need the "real" type of the objects. This is an restriction by a legacy code which basically cannot synchronize the two collection if they do not contain the same type objects.

Comment: Do they share any base type or interface that fulfills your needs?
I am a little unclear as to how the control works if it based on the type.
Surely something, somewhere has the knowledge of the type?

Comment: Hi Oliver,

As I am writing this message I understand that as I feared what I want to do is technically not possible in C#. Declaring a collection of a type that would be determined in the runtime is not possible in C# or at least not a good practice.

What I think I have to do is refactor the legacy code that puts such "big" restriction in a way that it allows me to be able to simply use a base class for the objects rather than their specific type which is determined at runtime.

Thank you for your comment and I will mark this as answered for now.

Comment: Unfortunately you may be right, generics are interpreted at compile time. As you have stated, while there are ways around the "problem" they normally originate as a stop-gap solution to a larger design issue. 

For me personally, if a number types are "sharing" a collection there should be some base type or interface that describes the common functionality that be used in a generic way throughout the remainder of the codebase.